# Trying to retrieve first 5 characters (only number & alphabet) from string in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string like that

> 1-a-bc-dxyz

I'd want to get `1-a-bc-d` ( first 5 characters, only number and alphabet)

Thanks

Comment: What do you want with input `1-a#bc%d(xyz` ? Or is a `-` the only special char?

Answer (score 4):

With gawk:

```
   awk '{ for ( i=1;i<=length($0);i++) { if ( match(substr($0,i,1),/[[:alnum:]]/)) { cnt++;if ( cnt==5) { print substr($0,1,i) } } } }' <<< "1-a-bc-dxyz"
```

Read each character one by one and then if there is a pattern match for an alpha-numeric character (using the match function), increment a variable cnt. When cnt gets to 5, print the string we have seen so far (using the substr function)

Output:

```
 1-a-bc-d
```

Comment: I'd want to get `1-a-bc-d`, not `1abcd`

Answer (score 1):

```
a='1-a-bc-dxyz'
count=0
for ((i=0;i<${#a};i++)); do
    if [[ "${a:$i:1}" =~ [0-9]|[a-Z] ]] && [[ $((++count)) -eq 5 ]]; then
        echo "${a:0:$((i+1))}"
        exit
    fi  
done
```

You can further shrink this as;

```
a='1-a-bc-dxyz'
count=0
for ((i=0;i<${#a};i++)); do [[ "${a:$i:1}" =~ [0-9]|[a-Z] ]] && [[ $((++count)) -eq 5 ]] && echo "${a:0:$((i+1))}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ echo 1-a-bc-dxyz | \
awk -F '' '{b=i="";while(gsub(/[0-9a-z]/,"&",b)<5)b=b $(++i);print b}' 
1-a-bc-d
```

Explained:

```
awk -F '' '{                        # separate each char to its own field
    b=i=""                          # if you have more than one record to process
    while(gsub(/[0-9a-z]/,"&",b)<5) # using gsub for counting (adjust regex if needed)
        b=b $(++i)                  # gather buffer
    print b                         # print buffer
}'
```

Comment: awk is the only way to do this as a one-liner. Great answer!

Comment: @nitinr708 Not the only one-liner, `sed` is shorter (see my answer).

Comment: It's customary to comment when downvoting. Oh, everyone was downvoted. Almost.

Answer (score 1):

GNU `sed` supports an option to replace the k-th occurrence and all after that.

```
echo "1-a-bc-dxyz" | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]//g6'
```

Comment: Apparently almost everyone was. I'll compensate, that is nice.

Comment: I agree, this is the simplest answer. You have my respect @Walter A

Answer (score 0):

Using Combination of sed & AWK

`echo 1-a-bc-dxyz | sed 's/[-*%$#@]//g' | awk -F '' {'print $1$2$3$4$5'}`

You can use for loop for printing character as well.

Comment: OP wants to see the delimiters as well, not `1abcd` but `1-a-bc-d`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '1-a-bc-dxyz' | grep -Eo '^[[:print:]](-*[[:print:]]){4}'
```

That is pretty simple.
Neither sed nor awk.

Comment: Very nice solution, but fails with `1-a-bc-d-xyz` (extra `-` in output)

Comment: Fails with `-a-bc-d-xyz` (output one letter short)

Comment: Be more specific, then.

Comment: Your approach works with `echo "1-a-bc-d-xyz" | grep -Eo '([^[:alnum:]]*[[:alnum:]]){5}'`.

Comment: Depends on the task.